# Can't convert double to format string

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I has number

123456789

After format the result must be

```
123,456,789.00
```

Here snippet

```
private val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
 val resultSubTotalAmount = 12345678901 / 100
 val resultFormatSubTotalAmount = decimalFormat.format(resultSubTotalAmount)
```

And here result:

resultFormatSubTotalAmount = **123,456,789**

But I need: **123,456,789.00**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
DecimalFormat("#,#,#.00")
```

- This only works for numbers `1.000.000 < x < 1.000.000.000` (since we require two `,`s with integers in between)
- and rounds the double down (a floor).

**Note**: we can use single `#`s in the DecimalFormat because

> the integer part is never discarded, no matter if the pattern is smaller than the number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round it down, you can always change the format:

```
DecimalFormat("#,###.00")
```